# Installing a Samsung 850 Evo SSD and migrating old HDD to SSD

Tags: system-installation, ssd, clone

I am entirely new to Linux and don't know the jargon. I have an old 32-bit Acer, with 2GB RAM and 120 GB Hard Drive. I have downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 and it runs. I want to transfer this to a Samsung 850 EVO 500 GB SSD. I plan to use this as my  main drive. How do I do this?

Comment: Yes 14.04 will nicely run on 2gb RAM in 32-bit mode. Unfortunately it is EOL (End of Life) and your question is technically off-topic. That said I'm sure you can find many 16.04 and 18.04 examples here of migrating from HDD to SSD. The same commands would apply in 14.04.

Comment: fyi: Ubuntu 14.04 was the 2014.April (thus 14.04 given the *yy.mm* format of Ubuntu releases) which had 5 years of supported life. Assuming you care about security, you'll have to release-upgrade to 16.04 so I'd use this chance to either re-install on the new sdd, especially if it's a new or *fresh-ish* install (*just `cp` the files you want to keep from $HOME*). Upgrading from a EOL release to supported release is on-topic here.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. At the moment Ubuntu 14.04 was the starting point. The issue with some of the later versions of Ubuntu is that I can't find any that support 32 bit machines. The real question is how to perform the migration process, since I am completely new to Linux, I am clueless.